# Negative-curvature behaviour of higher-rank symmetric spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, symmetric-spaces

Let $X$ be a symmetric space of noncompact type with $rk\ X\geq 2$ and let $G$ be the identity component of the isometry group. Pick points $p\in X$ and $\xi\in\partial_{\infty}X$, with $\xi$ regular, and consider the geodesic cone over $G\cdot\xi$ with tip at $p$ (let's call it $C_p(G\cdot\xi)$).

Is there a constant $b=b(X,\xi)\neq 0$ such that all geodesic triangles with vertices $p,q,r$, where $q,r\in C_p(G\cdot\xi)$, satisfy the $CAT(-b^2)$ condition?

Let's say we're considering only triangles with $\angle_p(q,r)<\alpha_0/2$, where $\alpha_0$ is the smallest Tits angle between two distinct points of $G\cdot\xi$, otherwise (if the angle is allowed to approach $\alpha_0$) the statement is clearly false. Also, by "$CAT(-b^2)$ condition" I mean that, for $x\in[p,q]$ and $y\in[p,r]$, the comparison angle $\angle_{\overline p}(\overline x,\overline y)$ in a space of constant curvature $-b^{2}$ decreases as $x$ and $y$ move towards $p$; this is equivalent to only some of the other notions of $CAT(-b^2)$ (see e.g. Bridson-Haefliger II.1.7) as $p$ plays a special role here.

The statement holds if we fix $q$ and $r$, since the triangle is not contained in any flat. One can also easily check that the sectional curvature of planes tangent to $C_p(G\cdot\xi)$ and containing the radial direction is negative and uniformly bounded away from zero. It's not hard to use this to prove that the statement is true as $q,r$ diverge, if $\angle_p(q,r)$ shrinks so that $r$ is at uniformly bounded distance from $[p,q]$ (more or less because, in this case, the distance between $x$ and $y$ in $X$ is comparable to their distance in the path metric of $C_p(G\cdot\xi)$ and one can use the sectional curvature bound and Rauch's comparison theorem).

However, the general case has to be handled differently as $C_p(G\cdot\xi)$ is not convex and I'm not aware of any way of controlling the behaviour of geodesics with endpoints in it (i.e. how close they come to being contained in apartments containing $p$).

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to explicitly compute the curvatures, say for the case of SL(n,R)/SO(n), in  Lie Algebra terms (i.e. commutators, Killing form)? Just to check whether the statement has a chance to be true.

Comment: Yeah, even in the general case one can compute the sectional curvatures (see e.g. Theorem IV.4.2 in Helgason's book) and, for $C_p(G\cdot\xi)$, they are negative and bounded away from zero in terms of the smallest positive eigenvalue of $ad_H$, where $H$ is a unit tangent vector pointing towards $\xi$.

Comment: At the very least you want q and r to be antipodal for the question to make sense. But since nonantipodal pairs are limits of antipodal you see that there cannot be any uniform CAT(-b) condition.

Comment: Right, I should have realised that, thanks... But what if we require that $pq$ and $pr$ point towards ideal points $\xi$ and $\xi'$, with $\xi'$ in a fixed compact subset of the set $C(\xi)$ of points antipodal to $\xi$ (still with small $\angle_p(q,r)$)? I'm starting to think it might be false also in this case, since one can still choose diverging $q$ and $r$ (converging to distinct ideal points) with diverging $d(p,[q,r])$, but I am not sure if this is a counterexample, given the asymmetricity of the CAT(-b) condition that I'm requiring...

Comment: This still does not work: You need some hypothesis to ensure that the rays $pq$, $pr$ to be both strongly asymptotic to a (nonunique!) geodesic which you will then denote $qr$. I see no  reason for such geodesic to exist.

Comment: Is it so clear that even this asymmetric CAT(-b) condition implies that $qr$ has to subconverge to a geodesic strongly asymptotic to the limits of $pq$ and $pr$ (as $q,r\in X$ diverge)? The CAT(-b) condition allows me to compare with constant curvature segments from a point on $pq$ to a point on $pr$, but not segments from $qp$ to $qr$ (for instance, $qp$ and $qr$ could point to ideal points of different types, or $\angle_q(p,r)$ could not be small). In fact, I'm not even sure if $qr$ has to subconverge to *any* geodesic. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: In CAT(-1) setting asymptotic geodesic rays are always strongly asymptotic (after reparameterization).

Comment: I know that, but I'm not asking the triangle $pqr$ to be CAT(-b). I'm asking for a weaker condition, in which $p$ is fixed and plays a special role (see paragraph 3 in my question).

Comment: In case it's not clear what I mean: consider the space obtained by glueing the segment $[1,2]$ to the unit circle in the complex plane and set $a=i$, $b=-i$, $c=2$. The triangle $abc$ (with $ab$ going through $-1$) is $CAT(-\infty)$ when "seen from $c$", but it’s definitely not a $CAT(-\infty)$ triangle. In the symmetric space, I’m just asking for $pqr$ to be $CAT(-b)$ when “seen from $p$”. It might well be that in in symmetric spaces being $CAT(-b)$ when seen from a vertex implies being $CAT(-b)$, but it doesn’t seem so obvious to me…